# React: In react class component, should I use !== to match nextState with currentState

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I have a question about react class component. I understand functional component is the latest technologies when working with react.

Normally if I need to check the current state/props with next states/props in ShouldComponentUpdate to decide whether the component should update based on the checks.

Should I use use clonedDeep or !== when comparing with arrray or objects. I understand clonedDeep is fully clone the object whereas !== is shallow check.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making a deep clone of the object?

Answer (score 0):

#### shallow vs deep

if you do shallow comparison you will get your code executed regardless and sometimes an error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` if your logic involves updating that same state, since references won't be the same on every update.

Therefore it would be useful to use some library to perform a deep comparison, or at least compare the properties you are interested into to run your code.

#### Get Previous State

Compare them it may sound difficult, since at first you don't have `prevState` at hand. To accomplish that you can take advantage of [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), creating a `usePrevious` custom hook like suggested in react [docs](https://reactjs.org/community/support.html) to store the previous state:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => { ref.current = value });
  return ref.current;
}
```

with that you can use at your component like:

```
  const [arr, setarr] = useState([1, 2, 3])
  const previousArr = usePrevious(arr)
```

#### Comparing states

Finally you would use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) (with your state and prevState as dependency) where you would do some validation to execute your code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const isEqual = _.isEqual(arr, previousArr)
    isEqual
      ? console.log('same content')
      : console.log('different content')
  }, [arr, previousArr])
```

**Note:** On Mount `previousArr` is `undefined`, this way they will be not equal. If you want to skip any action on Mount you may validate if `previousArr` is undefined.

[image: compare-objects]